# Does deepcopy use copy-on-write?

Tags: python, deep-copy, copy-on-write

I wonder if the python interpreter applies copy on write strategy when doing a deepcopy on mutable objects.

Also, I'd like to know if the deepcopy is performed also on nonmutable object (that would seem strange to me however)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not do copy-on-write.

It doesn't do a deep copy on some built-in immutable types, but any user-defined "immutable" types will be deep-copied.

[copy.py in the Python 2.7 standard library](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/copy.py) includes this message in its documentation:

> This version does not copy types like module, class, function, method, nor stack trace, stack frame, nor file, socket, window, nor array, nor any similar types.

`copy` handles immutable objects like this:

```
def _copy_immutable(x):
    return x
for t in (type(None), int, long, float, bool, str, tuple,
          frozenset, type, xrange, types.ClassType,
          types.BuiltinFunctionType, type(Ellipsis),
          types.FunctionType, weakref.ref):
    d[t] = _copy_immutable
for name in ("ComplexType", "UnicodeType", "CodeType"):
    t = getattr(types, name, None)
    if t is not None:
        d[t] = _copy_immutable
```

`deepcopy` uses a more complicated scheme that's too long to copy into this most, but the gist is the same. One interesting point is that `_deepcopy_tuple` iterates through its elements and don't create a new object until it finds an element that was copied.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] is not y[i]:
        y = tuple(y)
        break
else:
    y = x
```

Comment: +1 for providing that link. Lines 41-43 clearly state what is copied and what is not.

Comment: It seems to actually be smarter than that: According to my testing, `(1,[2,3])` will be copied, but `(1,(2,3))` will not. So apparently, it looks at the contained types as well as the container.

Comment: @happy Ha, I didn't even notice. I should include that in the answer.

Comment: Looking at the code, this answer is incorrect: The code you showed is for `copy`, not `deepcopy`.

Comment: I also found quite interesting that classes are not deepcopied. I wonder if this means that if I have `class MyClass: foo = [1,2,3]` then during a deepcopy `MyClass.foo` is NOT deepcopied, unless I redefine the deepcopy method. Taht would be tricky. I will try and see the result

Comment: @interjay My mistake. :( Correcting.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't it, just copies the objects. And it also must copy immutable objects if they reference mutables.

Comment: Ah I wasn't thinking about immutable objects referencing mutable ones. +1 for that. Also, does that mean that if I issue a deepcopy for 2 module objects even funcion objects are copied (i.e. I have 2 instances of the same funcion in memory)?

Comment: @happy_emi: functions aren't copied. Try `deepcopy(deepcopy) is deepcopy`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see:

```
>>> import copy
>>> x = [[1],[2],"abc"]
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> id(x[0])
4299612960
>>> id(y[0])
4299541608
>>> id(x[2])
4297774504
>>> id(y[2])
4297774504
```

For the first element of `x` and `y`, the copy is performed and the object has a new id.  The third element, an immutable string, is not copied.